# Find the sum $\sum_{i=0}^ \infty {-4 \choose i}3^{-i}$

Tags: combinatorics

Find the following sum:

$\sum_{i=0}^ \infty {-4 \choose i}3^{-i}$

My intuition is that it would following the pattern
 $1 +{n\choose 1}x+ {n \choose 2}x^{2} + . . . + x^{n}$ but I am still having some trouble solving this. Would anyone care to give me any hints or help me solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Negative Binomial Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NegativeBinomialSeries.html):
$$(x+a)^{-n}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty {-n\choose k}x^ka^{-n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty{-4\choose k}3^{-k} \Rightarrow \\
n=4,x=1,a=3$$
Hence:
$$(1+3)^{-4}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty {-4\choose k}1^k3^{-4-k} \Rightarrow \sum_{k=0}^\infty{-4\choose k}3^{-k}=3^4(1+3)^{-4}.$$

Comment: Thank you, I understand now.

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)

$$(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom nk x^k$$  for $|x|<1$

Comment: And if it isn't clear to OP, in this case, $x=\frac13$.

Comment: @DonThousand,Thanks for the input. Yes $$3^{-i}=\left(\dfrac13\right)^i$$

Comment: So is that where I would start, at $x=\frac{1} {3}$? Thanks for the help and sorry for being a little dense.

Comment: @MiltonP.,Can you identify  $n,x,k$

Comment: Yes, $x=3, n=4, k=-i$. Would the solution then be $(1+3)^{-4}$? Or, using $x=\frac{1} {3}$, $(1+\frac{1}{3})^{-4}$?